# How do I send transactions to RSK deployed smart contract functions via Ethers.js and Hardhat

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, rsk

I have followed this [Hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/) and trying to test a [demo smart contract](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/writing-and-compiling-contracts.html) on [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/) regtest blockchain.

Here is the `hardhat.config.js` setup I am using:

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.7.3',
  defaultNetwork: 'rskregtest',
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rskregtest: {
      url: 'http://localhost:4444',
    },
};
```

This is the test I am trying to perform:

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('Transactions', () => {
  it('Should transfer tokens between accounts', async () => {
    const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
    const [owner, addr1] = signers;
    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('Token');
    const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();
      
    console.log('Before transction');
    console.log('Owner balance: ', await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address));
    console.log('Addr1 balance: ', await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr1.address));

    // Transfer 50 tokens from owner to addr1
    await hardhatToken.connect(owner).transfer(addr1.address, 50);

    console.log('After transaction');
    console.log('Owner balance: ', await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address));
    console.log('Addr1 balance: ', await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr1.address));
      
    expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr1.address)).to.equal(50);
  });
});
```

I expect this test to pass, with the "owner balance" to be `999950` (total supply `1000000` minus `50`) and the "address1 balance" to be `50`.

However the test fails with the console output:

```sh
Before transction
Owner balance:  BigNumber { value: "1000000" }
Addr1 balance:  BigNumber { value: "0" }
After transction
Owner balance:  BigNumber { value: "1000000" }
Addr1 balance:  BigNumber { value: "0" }
```

Looks like the transfer transaction is being rejected and the tokens have not been transferred.

What am I doing wrong? How can I transfer RSK regtest deployed tokens from one account to another using Ethers.js and Hardhat?

Answer (score 5):

Your transaction is eventually being processed (not rejected). However, in your code you start querying the balances *before* waiting for the transaction to finalize.

First you need to send a transaction request and then `wait()` for the response. After receiving the response you can end up querying the balances.

```js
const txResponse = await hardhatToken
      .connect(owner)
      .transfer(addr1.address, 50);
await txResponse.wait();

console.log('After transaction');
console.log('Owner balance: ', await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address));
```

Ref: [`TransactionResponse.wait()` in ethers.js docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse)